# error when create an expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have this code:

```
public class InputMapper : BaseMapper<Input, InputDTO>
{
    private Guid _CompanyId;
    public InputMapper(Guid companyId)
    {
        _CompanyId=companyId;
    }

    public override Expression<Func<InputDTO, Input>> ToDomain()
    {
        return x=> new Input()
        {
            CompanyId => this._CompanyId, <--- HERE I GET AN ERROR
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Deduction = x.Deduction
        };
    } 
}
```

Why do I get error on the marked line:

```
Invalid initializer member declarator
```

?

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Side note, your constructor assignment is backwards. You want to assign _CompanyId the value of companyId, don't you?

Comment: @Brandon: Off course you right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've used a lambda expression, where I suspect you meant to just initialize a property:

```
 CompanyId => this._CompanyId,
```

should be

```
 CompanyId = this._CompanyId,
```

(Also note Brandon's comment - the assignment in your constructor is the wrong way round.)

Answer (score 1):

I think it should just be

```
return x=> new Input()
{ CompanyID = this._CompanyID, ....
```

You're don't want assign a lambda to the returned object's CompanyID member.